# How to configure Rendora for Caddy + Vue App

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, devops, caddy

I have a Caddy serving my vue app on my server. I would like to add Rendora for SEO reasons but I think it's not working.

I have set up everything (Caddy, Headless Chrome, Rendora) up and running but i can't get static html when i curl from local pc so i don't think rendora is working correctly. What i'm doing wrong? Here is my rendora config:

```
{
  "backend": {
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:80"
  },
  "target": {
    "url": "https://mywebsite.com"
  },
  "headless": {
    "waitAfterDOMLoad": 0,
    "internal": {
      "url": "http://127.0.0.1:9222"
    }
  },
  "output": {
    "minify": true
  },
  "filters": {
    "userAgent": {
      "defaultPolicy": "whitelist"
    }
  }
}
```